# <select> for an entity with composite keys - strategy needed

Tags: sql, forms, database-design, webforms, relational-database

So say I have database table **tours** (PK tour_id) holding region independent information and **tours_regional_details** (PK tour_id, region_id) holding region specific information.

Let's say I want to populate select control with entities from **tours_regional_details** table (my real scenarios are bit different, just imagine this for the sake of simplicity).

So, how would you tackle this? My guts says concatenate PKs into delimited strings, like "pk1|pk2" or "pk1,pk2" and use that as value of select control. While it works, feels dirty and possibly needs additional validation steps before splitting the string again, which again feels dirty.

I don't want to start a composite vs single pk holy war, but may this be a bad database design decision on my part? I always believed identifying relationships and composite keys are there for a reason, but I feel tempted to alter my tables and just stuff them with auto incremental IDs and unique constraints. I'm just not sure what kind of a fresh hell will that introduce.

I am a little bit flabbergasted that I encounter this for the first time now after so many years.

**EDIT:** Yes, there is a table **regions** (PK region_id) but is mostly irrelevant for the topic. While in some scenarios two select boxes would make sense, let's say here they don't, let's say I want only one select box and want to select from:

- Dummy tour (Region 1)
- Dummy tour (Region 2)
- Another dummy tour (region 3)
- ...

Comment: I suppose in your example the first select would identify the tour_id, but where does the region_id value come from? Is there another region table who's PK is region_id? If so, depending on how you are fetching your values you can pass both ids, but yes in addition to sanitizing, you should validate they are within the set of expected ids before querying the DB with them.

Comment: Time to read a textbook on intro to information modeling & database design.

Comment: @philipxy Intro? I don't think so, but thanks anyways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composite primary keys aren't bad database design. In an ideal world, our programming languages and UI libraries would support tuples and relations as first-class values, so you'd be able to assign a pair of values as the value of an option in your dropdown control. However, since they generally only support scalar variables, we're stuck trying to encode or reduce our identifiers.

You can certainly add surrogate keys / autoincrement columns (and unique constraints on the natural keys where available) to every table. It's a very common pattern, most databases I've seen have at least some tables set up like this. You may be able to keep existing composite foreign keys as is, or you may want/need to change them to reference the surrogate primary keys instead.

The risk with using surrogate keys for foreign keys is that your access paths in the database become fixed. For example, let's assume `tours_regional_details` had a primary key `tours_regional_detail_id` that's referenced by a foreign key in another table. Queries against this other table would always need to join with `tours_regional_details` to obtain the `tour_id` or `region_id`. Natural keys allow more flexible access paths since identifiers are reused throughout the database. This becomes significant in deep hierarchies of dependent concepts. These are exactly the scenarios where opponents of composite keys complain about the "explosion" of keys, and I can at least agree that it becomes cumbersome to remember and type out joins on numerous columns when writing queries.

You could duplicate the natural key columns into the referencing tables, but storing redundant information requires additional effort to maintain consistency. I often see this done for performance or convenience reasons where surrogate keys were used as foreign keys, since it allows querying a table without having to do all the joins to dereference the surrogate identifiers. In these cases, it might've been better to reference the natural key instead.

If I'm allowed to return to my ideal world, perhaps DBMSs could allow naming and storing joins.

In practice, surrogate keys help balance the complexity we have to deal with. Use them, but don't worship them.